# Writing Request Payload property on httprequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, payload

I am trying to develop a browser extension that will help people to some stuff way easier.
One of the things that I need to do is sending couple of http requests.

I need to recreate requests that site makes when doing certain things.
Now site uses Request Payload which is my first time using(used form data),therefore I don't know how to make Request Payload same as when site sends request.

```
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    url = 'https://www.hidden.com/api/v1/tipuser/',
    data = 'steam_64=76561198364912967&tip_asset_ids=[]&tip_balance=0',
    token ='...';

request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log("The request and response was successful!");
   }
};
request.open('POST', url, true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'text/plain');
request.setRequestHeader('authorization', token);
request.send(data);
```

This is my code and after sending it you can see how my Request Payload looks.
I have been having difficulties for days now and I searched online but couldn't find solution to this.I know that I just have to write it differently .

[This is site's request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3v09.png)

[This is my request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4Kdb.png)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try sending your request as application/json and build your data object like in the example below?

Your Content-type request header should be application/json

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest(),
url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/',
data = {
    steam_64: '76561198364912967',
    tip_asset_ids: [], 
    tip_balance: 0,
    token: '',
};

request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log("The request and response was successful!");
   }
};
request.open('POST', url, true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
request.setRequestHeader('authorization', data.token);
request.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: It worked, but can you explain little bit more the difference between what I was sending and what this is, I am new to this so it would really help out :)

Comment: To see the difference between the two data formats, you can console.log(data) and console.log(JSON.stringify(data)).  It looks like the server is expecting the payload in JSON format, rather than the first, which is a url encoded string.  JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a language independent format used to represent data objects in a string format.  I would recommend reading up on JSON [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON] for a better explanation than I can give here.